# Authorize.net payement transaction

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have connect Authorize.net using direct connection. Currently we have used Visa and American Express for payment .
For adding this two feature "payment for MasterCard and Discover" we have need to do some changes in code or not?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything with Authorize.Net. You need to contact your merchant account provider and have them add MasterCard and Discover Card to your merchant account.